# harpjs not compiling stylus with harp server

Tags: node.js, pug, stylus, harp

[harpjs](http://harpjs.com) won't *compile* stylus `*.styl` stylesheets when using harp server, *`harp server`*.

This is the error I get when I try to use `main.styl` as a stylesheet, linking it with `main.css` within my `index.jade` document (Jade is working perfectly, with no errors, I also tried using html documents instead of jade, but the issue was not resolved unfortunately.)

[image]

However, as soon as I add an empty `main.css` file in my file structure, the error disappears, although, no styles are applied (it's an empty document, what should I expect though right?)

So, I was wondering if anyone has come across this error, or abnormality before, and if so, how they fixed it,

**Things I've Tried**

- re-installing stylus (`npm install -g stylus`)
- re-installing harp (`npm install -g harp`)
- re-installing jade (`npm install -g pug`)
- re-installing pug (`npm install -g pug`)
- trying a different device
- trying a different os; (Linux instead of OS X)

All of which, unfortunately, didn't fix the issue.

Comment: works with SASS or Less?

Comment: Less works as expected, just not stylus unfortunately. (I tested this just by running `harp init myProj`.

Comment: Sorry but I can't reproduce your error. Works fine for me. I suppose you don't have stylus sytax errors, isn't it?

Comment: That's ok, and no, zero syntax errors in my stylus code, I tried compiling it directly and it works, just really want it to work with harp!

Comment: I reproduce the issue upgrading nodejs to version 6, before I had 4.6.0 version and worked fine. Which version of node you have?

Comment: I have version 6.8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't really fix it entirely, however, I did find a workaround.

As I use sublime text, I found a really nice stylus plugin, which allow for compilation on save, a really cool feature. So, basically, I'm just using harp as a jade preprocessor now which is ok, but hey, it sort of works now.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution. Terraform is the pre-processor engine of harp and uses stylus 0.53.0, I update to stylus 0.54.5 (the lastest version) and now works.

I search *terraform* in *harp* directory: `harp\node_modules\terraform\node_modules` and update stylus: `npm install stylus@0.54.5 --save`

Comment: Why downvote? Is a valid solution for the problem, I spend much time searching a solution and make a lot of test. Something is wrong in my answer?